# How to load .so files of two pre built libraries in project android?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build, android.mk

I have two projects .so files. project one contains prebuilt openssl .so files build using CMake. and second projects contains some .so files which is build using Android.mk. Now My problem is i want to use both projects in my new project. but i am not getting how to write CMake or Android.mk.

here is code of CMake of first project

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


             add_library(openssl SHARED IMPORTED)
             set_target_properties (openssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libcrypto.so )

             add_library(prebuilt_ssl SHARED IMPORTED)
             set_target_properties (prebuilt_ssl PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libssl.so )






# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

include_directories(openssl-armeabi-v7a/include/)
find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libcrypto.a
                      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/openssl-armeabi-v7a/lib/libssl.a

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib} )
```

and Android.mk of second project

```
#
# Copyright 2009 Cedric Priscal
# 
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License. 
#

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

TARGET_PLATFORM := android-3
LOCAL_MODULE    := serial_port
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SerialPort.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Please help me for writing CMake or Android.mk? which is easy CMake or Android.mk ?

Comment: You want to link `libnative_lib` against `libserial_port`?

Comment: @Michael yes I want to use both

Answer (score 0):

Google seems to encourage us to use *CMake* more these days. For simple builds, like your **libserial_port.so**, translation from **Android.mk** to **CMakeLists.txt** is not hard:

```
add_library(serial_port SHARED SerialPort.c)
target_link_libraries(serial_port log)
```

(remember, you don't need *find_library* for **log**).